# elements in the list to be printed as part of bash command in python

Tags: python

I have a list as below

```
list_item = [ten , hundred, thousand , million]
```

How the print that as a part of the bash script as a variable ,

```
import os
for i in list_item()
   os.system("cat  $list_item[i] >> /tmp/tmp.txt| ")
```

the above format is not working .

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
list_item = ['ten' , 'hundred', 'thousand' , 'million']
for i in list_item:
  os.system("cat " + i +" >> /tmp/tmp.txt| ")
```